# How to preprocessing category data for discriminant analysis

Tags: discriminant-analysis, data-preprocessing

I want to do discriminant analysis for five set observation data (five category) using LDA.  From references, most of them suggesting to apply some preprocessing first (i.e. transformation, center, scale).
My question is, should I preprocessing each set category independently, as

```
ps1 <- prep(s1)
ps2 <- prep(s2)
ps3 <- prep(s3)
ps4 <- prep(s4)
ps5 <- prep(s5)
psall <- bind(ps1, ps2, ps3, ps4, ps5)
lda(psall)
```

or
preprocessing them all as one, like

```
all <- bind(s1, s2, s3, s4, s5)
psall <- prep(all)
lda(psall)
```

Comment: All as one! Separate preprocessing doesn't make sense: imagine that you get a new data point and want to classify it with your LDA into one of the five classes. How should you preprocess it? Which of the five class-specific transformations would you use? That's of course impossible to say, hence you should use one fixed transformation for the whole dataset.

Comment: @amoeba That should be an answer - and answer I'd like to upvote.